# Show that the union of Θ and o is not O

Tags: asymptotics, big-o-notation

> Show that: $\Theta(n\log n)\cup o(n\log n)\neq O(n\log n)$

I tried to start this in many ways but I don't really know how... intuitively isn't $\Theta \cup o = o$? So that would mean that I would have to just show that $o(n \log n) \neq O(n \log n) $  Which would be easier I think. But I don't know how to go about this formally..

Comment: "intuitively isn't $\Theta \cup o=o$?" -- no, intuitively $\Theta(m)$ means "roughly equal to $m$" and $o(m)$ means "much less than $m$", so it's more intuitive to think of these as being disjoint. But in any case, intuition won't help you much here -- each of these three expressions is a set of functions (of $n$), and you need to work with the definitions of these sets. You need to find some function of $n$ that is in the LHS but not the RHS, or vice versa.

Comment: The definition of o means that in a sense, o(f(n)) is an “integral” full step smaller than f(n). I would try to find a function that satisfies f(n)/n or f(n)/log n or f(n)/(n log n)^0.5 goes to zero

Answer (score 4):

An obvious function is 
$$
f(n) = \begin{cases}
n \log n & \text{if $n$ is even}, \\
0 & \text{if $n$ is odd}. 
\end{cases}
$$

It's in $O (n \log n)$, it's not in $o (n \log n)$ and not in $\Theta(n \log n)$.

By the way: Every function in $\Theta(f(n)))$ is in $O(f(n))$, just take the larger constant from the $\Theta$ definition. And every function in $o(f(n))$ is also in $O(f(n))$, choose $c = 1$ and make $n$ large enough. But not the other way around.

$O(f(n))$ contains functions that have infinitely many values between $c_1 f(n)$ and $c_2 f(n)$, but also infinitely many small values. So a function $g(n) = f(n)$ for infinitely many $n$, and $g(n) = 0$ for infinitely many $n$ where $f(n) \ne 0$ is in $O (f(n))$, but not in $\Theta(f(n))$ and not in $o (f(n))$.

Comment: To add to that, the intuition that $\Theta \cup o = O$ holds for "well behaving functions". Consider the definition of the function classes using limits. If $\lim f(x)/g(x)$ exists, then $g \in O(f)$ if  and only if $g \in \Theta(f) \cup o(f)$.